# Why is a child view recalculated after parent view is modified so as to exclude it?

Tags: swiftui

If you run the following code, and click on the button twice, 1 second after the button is clicked the second time, the code will crash on the
`return someString! + " subView"` line, with an Unexpectedly found nil error.

in the output window will be the following lines of text:

```
ContentView someString == nil, not calculating SubView
ContentView someString != nil
SubView, someString != nil
ContentView someString == nil, not calculating SubView
SubView, someString == nil, will crash
TestSubViews/ContentView.swift:21: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

code here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SubView: View {
  @Binding var someString : String?
  var body: some View {
    Text(calculatedText())
  }
  func calculatedText() -> String {
    if (someString == nil) {
      print("SubView, someString == nil, will crash")
    } else {
      print("SubView, someString != nil")
    }
    return someString! + " subView"
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var someString : String? = nil
  @State var buttonText = "click me"
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      if someString != nil {
        let _ = print("ContentView someString != nil")
        SubView(someString: $someString)
      } else {
        let _ = print("ContentView someString == nil, not calculating SubView")
        Text("no subview")
      }
      Button(buttonText) {
        if someString == nil {
          someString = "some string"
          buttonText = "click me to crash in 1 second"
        } else {
          Task {
            try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            someString = nil
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is why, after the line "ContentView someString == nil" is shown, which only happens in the case where we're not calculating a SubView, I then get the SubView being calculated.

Edit from comment:
Is the problem here that the time when the SubView is removed from the hierarchy undefined?  This example is a bit contrived in my attempt to simplify down the problem, mostly I'm trying to understand exactly what is happening here.

Thanks much for any insight :)

Comment: You're relying on what I assume is undefined behavior: when a `View`'s body will get removed from the calculation hierarchy. Rely on safe unwrapping of optionals and you'll be fine.

Comment: I updated the question slightly based on your comment, thanks for that.

Comment: Reread @jnpdx 's comment. You are asking us to tell you the unknowable. You can't depend on the timing of removal, or recompilation of various views. That is why we safely unwrap. Also, review [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) several times. I watch this regularly.

Comment: yeh -- he said he assumed it was undefined behavior, I was just hoping to clarify if his assumption was valid.  Sounds like it is, and it makes sense.  I'll check that video -- watched it once when I first started on SwiftUI, but haven't in ages, thanks for the suggestion :)